# Applying a list of functions to a value with Java8 stream api

Tags: java, java-8, reduce

I want a take a single log message pojo `LoggedExchange` and apply a bunch of transformations to it. The transformations are UnaryOperators in a list:

```
List<ConditionalTransform> transforms = new ArrayList<>();
```

where `ConditionalTransform` implements `UnaryOperator<LoggedExchange>` and my current solution is using reduce like this:

```
public LoggedExchange transform(LoggedExchange original) {
    return transforms.stream().reduce(original, (o, t) -> t.apply(o), (m1, m2) -> m2);
}
```

Running this in parallel does not make sense, as there is no way to do the combining of two messages (the `(m1,m2) -> m2` is there just to make the compiler happy).

Is there a better way to do this (like somehow composing all the `ConditionalTranforms`?) and if not, should the `combiner` function throw an exception or something as I can't support parallel execution?

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) states that most of these operations should be possible to do with `map` and `reduce` but I don't see how.

Comment: Are you *required* to use streams?

Comment: Nope, I'm just _tempted_ to use streams :)

Comment: You should never provide a combiner which silently does something, if you *know* that this is not appropriate. Provide a *throwing* combiner if you really have no alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public LoggedExchange transform(LoggedExchange original) {
    return transforms.stream().reduce(UnaryOperator.identity(), (a, b) -> ((LoggedExchange o) -> b.apply(a.apply(o)))).apply(original);
}
```

This constructs a single `UnaryOperator<LoggedExchange>` which applies all of the functions in `transforms` in turn, then calls it with the input value.

Alternatively, there's always the straightforward looping version:

```
public LoggedExchange transform(LoggedExchange value) {
    for(UnaryOperator<LoggedExchange> transform : transforms)
        value = transform.apply(value);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: The first example does not compile for me. The last `.apply` does not exist and the `reduce` operation is not legal, IDE says `target type of lambda conversion must be an interface`.

Comment: @vertti Fixed. I didn't notice that `reduce` with one argument returns an `Optional` (which makes sense in case the stream has no elements).

Comment: Alright, now the last .apply works but the `(LoggedExchange o) -> b.apply(a.apply(o))` part still complains "target type of lambda conversion must be an interface".

Comment: @vertti [Compiles for me](http://ideone.com/hCdo4g) (obviously that example doesn't run because it doesn't have a main method, but it does compile)

Comment: Note: if `transforms` is a `Collection<Function<LoggedExchange, LoggedExchange>>` then you can use `.reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)`. (If it's a `Collection<UnaryOperator<LoggedExchange>>` and you do this, then type inference fails, even though `UnaryOperator<T>` extends `Function<T, T>`)

Comment: @immibis: That can be fixed by using `Function.identity()` instead of `UnaryOperator.identity()` and the three-arg version: `.reduce(Function.<T>identity(), Function::andThen, Function::andThen)`. That’ll work with `Stream<UnaryOperator<T>>` as well.

Answer (score -2):

I don’t think you are really reducing anything. I think you are instead just mapping a string in another string.

I would write this:

```
trasforms
    .forEach(transformation -> transformation.apply(original));
```

And remember to declare original as final.

Comment: That is nothing but a costly noop.

Comment: Why is that? Did I miss something?

Comment: Because you're transforming an original value into something else, and do nothing with the result of the transformation.